# How can I fix chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener not working in my ChromeApp on ChromeOS versions 110 & above?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

```
serviceApiCall: function () {
                chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(this.addChromeListner); // This calling is not working
            }

addChromeListner: function (port) {

//this function called propely in chromeOS 109 version. But after that this code not responding. 

}
```

This code is from my OLD ChromeApp , which is working fine is older chromeOS version. But not working in latest ChromeOS version.

In manifest.json, i am using manifest version (2). And i have tried to check with manifest version 3. but that was not working in backgound.js file.

Anyone who is solved, please reply.

Comment: There's no [MCVE](/help/mcve) in the question, so it's impossible to say what's wrong.